# dash appをherokuにデプロイするときのエラー "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.7.2"

Tags: python, heroku, dash

当方、初めてdashアプリを作成しherokuを通じてデプロイしようとしたところエラーが解決できず行き詰っております。
具体的には、以下の公式ドキュメント
https://dash.plotly.com/deployment
に従ってAnaconda Prompt上でデプロイしようとしており、"4. Initialize Heroku, add files to Git, and deploy"のところで

```
git push heroku main
```

と入力すると、以下のエラーメッセージが表示されます
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

恐れ入りますが、上記エラーの解決方法をご教示いただけますと幸いです。
なお、エラーにあたって以下を試したものの、解決に至っておりません。
・"requrements.txt"内に記載ある"anaconda-client==1.7.2"のうち"=="以降を削除
・使用しているpythonのバージョンである"python-3.7.4"を記載したruntime.txtをルートフォルダに格納

よろしくお願いいたします